# PHP Android RSA communication issues

Tags: java, php, android, rsa, phpseclib

## UPDATE

Fixed the initial issue, (trying to do a simple RSA agaisnt a datablock), but still have issues

Updated all 4 keys, java code, and the new output errors from java

---

I have tried everything i have spent the last 48 hours trying so damn hard to figure all of this out. To the degree of putting a page together on the server detailing the entier situation.

Long story short i have encryption working perfectly on the server with php, i just cant seem to decrypt clientside (haven't tried encrypting yet), i keep getting so many errors, current is data to big for RSA block, but i've triple checked all my encoding and i just cant seem to find anything.

Using spongycastle on java and phpseclib 3.8

http://lunarmessaging.net/test.php

(3 base bin links for PHP encryption/decryption, and the super simple android application i have made to test this)

i am so lost here its not even funny

Edit: updated with as much information as humanly possible

## Example of operations

Basically I am creating a keyed array to call a function on the server

{"CLASS":"test","FUNCTION":"helloWorld","ARGS":{"value1":"derp","value2":"boogah boogah boogah"}}

1. Turned into JSON from array
2. Encrypted with the server public key, this becomes the payload
3. Base64 the user public key, becomes the response
4. Create a JSON object with both of those and Base64 / Urlencode the whole thing
5. Call url with fancy Encrypted API IE: lunarmessaging.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%3D

a sample response looks like this

```
{
    "ENCRYPTION":2,
    "RESPONSE":"LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQVUJMSUMgS0VZLS0tLS0gTUlHZk1BMEdDU3FHU0liM0RRRUJBUVVBQTRHTkFEQ0JpUUtCZ1FEcDlwbnhIZkc2dllrRDljckIxbE1Xazl5ZiBuSTJ3aW1uUkF6TjlNdWJkVjJnWmNOTWhxcVkwcGYvbjhCU1ZWc3phc2lVL2pTOS9rbWpzcG1SS0JiTVI2eHlYIDNMYWxvM1djaUhiNW1MQXFQRnFyYXY5QXFMT000WVNRUC90T2R1cVZ3c2ExVEVwcmNFaVNBWjJsRHZRR3RaNE4gUzd5RldrRncrN3NNb3Y4M2RRSURBUUFCIC0tLS0tRU5EIFBVQkxJQyBLRVktLS0tLQ==",
    "PAYLOAD":"MrLWmvaQTIdNjF3CopGw+uA3QqK33cBEyIenFGi+V\/7JZFSQq\/6W8UlWLwdZH4n\/fMIMsEHD\/EpOQxZ7rtHEaGqZxRjg8YyecgUvYozpxm9kdxPBBIhXT2xUvpx08WJkvPqIWhR6ykS7RHvvJ3Tsz0ODvRHeHIARetrCdNLM\/z9c61xFh9vo1EGcqfBMso385M6telcOOsBeDA4\/mM6oa1d8wWOseQRnEOzTaSooIDR\/O6\/G382t5Xqf5df1JdD9dUvcrju3RvEKR+wuHJjvISCcvQ1uYf9y\/mNuA+6Vib1BJWdUNLCj7abJoxWe31RU60lktx7WxV8GG3d+rLFnBg=="
}
```

6. Server then reverses the whole process, call basically the plaintext API EXAMPLE URL IE: lunarmessaging.net/api/test/helloWorld/value1/derp/value2/boogah%20boogah%20boogah

a sample response looks like this

```
{
    value1: "derp",
    value2: "boogah boogah boogah",
    test: "Hey It Works",
    exit: {
        code: 0,
        message: ""
    }
}
```

7. Repeats the above process (with userpub / serverpub respectivly), and this is the data you see on the above encrypted url

CODE EXAMPLES AND MORE (example keys at the end)

### test encryption (php similating user encrypting things)

`

```
<?php
    $callData = array(  "CLASS" => "test", "FUNCTION" => "helloWorld", "ARGS" => array( "value1" => "derp", "value2" => "boogah boogah boogah" ));

    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS1);
    $rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1);

    $rsa->loadKey($srvPub);
    $serverData = base64_encode( $rsa->encrypt( json_encode($callData)));

    $serverData = array("ENCRYPTION" => 1, "RESPONSE" => base64_encode($usrPub), "PAYLOAD" => $serverData);

    $serverData = base64_encode( json_encode( $serverData));
    $serverData = urlencode($serverData);

    $url = $baseURL."api/encrypted/".$serverData;
?>`
```

### the server decrypting the request (BOTH PHP FUNCTIONS FUNCTION AS WANTED)

`

```
<?php
    //start RSA and do a general decode of the message
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS1);
    $rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1);

    $inputData = json_decode( base64_decode( $_GET['encrypted']), true);

    //decrypt the payload sent to the server
    //this is our client -> server encryption
    $rsa->loadKey($srvPriv);
    $payload = json_decode( $rsa->decrypt ( base64_decode( $inputData['PAYLOAD'])), true);
    $response = base64_decode( $inputData['RESPONSE']);

    //Call the function based on the sent information
    //this is the stage where its plaintext on the server
    $serverCall = rest::callFunction($payload);
    //var_dump($payload);

    //generate a response for the client
    $rsa->loadKey($usrPub);
    $serverCall = base64_encode( $rsa->encrypt( json_encode($serverCall)));

    $backToUser = array(    "ENCRYPTION" => 2,
                            "RESPONSE" => base64_encode($srvPub),
                            "PAYLOAD" => $serverCall);

    $backToUser = json_encode($backToUser);
    echo $backToUser;
?>`
```

### Java Application

`
    package lunar.messaging.apitest;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.DERNull;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.pkcs.PKCSObjectIdentifiers;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPrivateKey;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.AsymmetricBlockCipher;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.engines.RSAEngine;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.util.PrivateKeyFactory;
import org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.BCRSAPrivateKey;
import org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.BCRSAPublicKey;
import org.spongycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.spongycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml.Encoding;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    static {
        Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void encryptedTest(View view) throws Exception {

        //String usrPriv = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 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 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

        //String usrPriv = "MIICWwIBAAKBgQCDbFBVWh94E0/2tmAZJ0E0oeX3DHuz/s2URtfJUTX5P7sp5MgD zKQ5kWdXbPPprG9d9QGl9koQFkMvaPZQScvUH/yGHEKyoYQLJfzWA85L1uliSmPt wb/5R26gLS9xqjetCV+VJpIXQ7FwUTkH0fFFpgMrbNASYIarPku7bfv+3wIDAQAB AoGAA3J43PRDNQwUod0AwkgkTrQcaxF5wSviyovdJxupNcN1LlEg6fCZMiVdN47V CwEJ3sYJaAgAw1FCK+Et7McywHCS3Cw61vy/vt5+q9LwYE5x+5NhbJOV6UPgR34F ClZSPA7ELZmaK5IKh97+eAyTsUcOJxejwWeoBLQdHZqrNWkCQQCHzDl3cvdzYDC0 c07CLhsZjhTm4BMM/+oT3wOhAYA70ti7s0JEcwCB7bYkVE2ZLUFGgLk+emG7pIfX I9NUmIILAkEA98DLERPBy0tf/gpy6W7cLXQFQWlaLvGsWQI6XL4MVSP9tD8bqk8q YiPx8ZI3m9ane3FyXF/1iNKYvDfiLKCu/QJAOMmQZoEvNZJOC8gEcXNyZbdiykF9 9fu22WRzUgscoufDNor59UHaPns3pe2THbEtENyXmqb2488j9zXGFCRKjQJAV85p ae0BowZcyBF19ouG10kmT6+B+d9HQOiMPLBSeJ5f3VD8ghi6obuxlPdIZB/ojdSA PoL3530UCqkXrM9qFQJANy5KrTAtH4mTY7KW9BymA8bQRVBgQdAvNRCsBOCjnIPj M26rCOjS1BbrmuHKtoZztQeH9G+cu/iFtCPAvf0eig==";

        String usrPriv = "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";


apiRequest testAsynch = new apiRequest();
        String urlRequest = null;
        try {
            urlRequest = testAsynch.execute("http://lunarmessaging.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%3D").get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            urlRequest = "Fail 1";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            urlRequest = "Fail 2";
        }

        JSONObject responseJSON = null;
        String response = null;
        String payload = null;

        try {
            responseJSON = new JSONObject(urlRequest);
            response = responseJSON.getString("RESPONSE");
            payload = responseJSON.getString("PAYLOAD");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("[ENCRYPTION]", "Response: " + response);
        Log.d("[ENCRYPTION]", "Payload: " + payload);


        byte[] derp = Base64.decode(payload, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.d("[payload]",Arrays.toString(derp));

        String welp = decrypt(usrPriv,payload);
        Log.d("[OUTPUT]", " " + welp);
    }

    public String decrypt (String privateKeyin, String encrypted){

        try {

            Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

            String value = "";
            String key = privateKeyin;
            Log.d("CRYPT", "started");

            AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey =
                    (AsymmetricKeyParameter) PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(Base64.decode(privateKeyin, Base64.DEFAULT));

            AsymmetricBlockCipher e = new RSAEngine();

            Log.d("CRYPT", "created param");
            //e = new org.spongycastle.crypto.encodings.PKCS1Encoding(e);
            //e = new org.spongycastle.crypto.engines.RSAEngine();
            e = new org.spongycastle.crypto.encodings.PKCS1Encoding(e);
            //e = new org.spongycastle.crypto.encodings.OAEPEncoding(e);
            e.init(false, privateKey);

            String inputdata = encrypted;
            byte[] messageBytes = Base64.decode(inputdata.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);

            Log.d("CRYPT", "decoding payload");

            int i = 0;
            int len = e.getInputBlockSize();
            while (i < messageBytes.length)
            {
                if (i + len > messageBytes.length)
                    len = messageBytes.length - i;

                byte[] hexEncodedCipher = e.processBlock(messageBytes, i, len);
                value = value + new String(hexEncodedCipher);
                i += e.getInputBlockSize();
            }
            Log.d("CRYPT", "printing output");

            System.out.println(value);

            return value;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getHexString(byte[] b) throws Exception {
        String result = "";
        for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
            result +=
                Integer.toString( ( b[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    } 
}


class apiRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    protected void onPreExecute (){
        //Log.d("PreExceute","On pre Exceute......");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...arg0) {
        //Log.d("[INFO]",arg0[0]);

        String response = postData(arg0[0]);

        //Log.d("[INFO]","END TESTING HTTP");

        return response;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Log.d("onPostExecute",""+result);
    }

    public String postData(String url) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            // Execute HTTP Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            InputStream stream = null;
            String result = null;

            String encoding = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(response.getEntity());
            encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;

            try {
                stream = AndroidHttpClient.getUngzippedContent(response.getEntity());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            InputStreamEntity unzEntity = new InputStreamEntity(stream,-1);

            try {
                result = EntityUtils.toString(unzEntity, encoding);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}


`
```

### java stacktrace

```
11-12 13:56:22.092: D/[ENCRYPTION](13919): Response: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFVCTElDIEtFWS0tLS0tIE1JR0pBb0dCQUpCZk40cFpxQmdpb3Q1NThCd1VZWitmNlNuc2ZvanZ0RDBUVkxlV2tnYkVSU1pKNTV3c3dzTGsgc3MrcmZadGtNL1E0QlhKMnI5bWI3RUlZYVphUkRXVFZta3I2RzRMM041WXZIRlVWZUhyczEveXpWZDBBNGoycyBkZFI5clUvYTZUQWN3Z3FmUTJtTUFVM01HcGZhRTJZVTBSN2VpMGxEQUY2V2RFQ1MyRXh6QWdNQkFBRT0gLS0tLS1FTkQgUlNBIFBVQkxJQyBLRVktLS0tLQ==
11-12 13:56:22.092: D/[ENCRYPTION](13919): Payload: BUoW99FG2YXJdQR651O/JMiQFi1Hl4XT/w7MmtMAAophZdSkGWGGJ/3MetLU90FCEN1sXn/bUDWEymfIFxtQ51BRbWM0Zrpe86AKf5mhCF7mPt2eY9nu+CEAt2xmwSOOqg1lnh5LeZS0xMd/QT4eudre58brAL3fSUXsYv4sVZh+4KkUNHaDplq75UfT670XYn8h6azc+ld/AdGBHvU9J1jnoAoryWpFYMCDE74FPaJLr2WhkAFMuGDjabH1hkucH2I4FF1zeX6cDwdd1ThIaYEIfPWvfWwacsOtKQUobDFm5HxvPrPGkXkmXbGdbr/6unyoMo3NrCRYE7CTBDmX3w==
11-12 13:56:22.092: D/[payload](13919): [5, 74, 22, -9, -47, 70, -39, -123, -55, 117, 4, 122, -25, 83, -65, 36, -56, -112, 22, 45, 71, -105, -123, -45, -1, 14, -52, -102, -45, 0, 2, -118, 97, 101, -44, -92, 25, 97, -122, 39, -3, -52, 122, -46, -44, -9, 65, 66, 16, -35, 108, 94, 127, -37, 80, 53, -124, -54, 103, -56, 23, 27, 80, -25, 80, 81, 109, 99, 52, 102, -70, 94, -13, -96, 10, 127, -103, -95, 8, 94, -26, 62, -35, -98, 99, -39, -18, -8, 33, 0, -73, 108, 102, -63, 35, -114, -86, 13, 101, -98, 30, 75, 121, -108, -76, -60, -57, 127, 65, 62, 30, -71, -38, -34, -25, -58, -21, 0, -67, -33, 73, 69, -20, 98, -2, 44, 85, -104, 126, -32, -87, 20, 52, 118, -125, -90, 90, -69, -27, 71, -45, -21, -67, 23, 98, 127, 33, -23, -84, -36, -6, 87, 127, 1, -47, -127, 30, -11, 61, 39, 88, -25, -96, 10, 43, -55, 106, 69, 96, -64, -125, 19, -66, 5, 61, -94, 75, -81, 101, -95, -112, 1, 76, -72, 96, -29, 105, -79, -11, -122, 75, -100, 31, 98, 56, 20, 93, 115, 121, 126, -100, 15, 7, 93, -43, 56, 72, 105, -127, 8, 124, -11, -81, 125, 108, 26, 114, -61, -83, 41, 5, 40, 108, 49, 102, -28, 124, 111, 62, -77, -58, -111, 121, 38, 93, -79, -99, 110, -65, -6, -70, 124, -88, 50, -115, -51, -84, 36, 88, 19, -80, -109, 4, 57, -105, -33]
11-12 13:56:22.177: D/dalvikvm(13919): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 305K, 10% free 9851K/10848K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
11-12 13:56:22.202: D/CRYPT(13919): started
11-12 13:56:22.207: I/System.out(13919): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Integer
11-12 13:56:22.207: D/[OUTPUT](13919):  null
```

### Server Keys

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIICXAIBAAKBgQCQXzeKWagYIqLeefAcFGGfn+kp7H6I77Q9E1S3lpIGxEUmSeec LMLC5LLPq32bZDP0OAVydq/Zm+xCGGmWkQ1k1ZpK+huC9zeWLxxVFXh67Nf8s1Xd AOI9rHXUfa1P2ukwHMIKn0NpjAFNzBqX2hNmFNEe3otJQwBelnRAkthMcwIDAQAB AoGARi9D3OpBIZqU+vrkk4IFA4jF3S+vQ/rj8F0ZbjawvsFjrH15Lx9Df2OW2gZQ hd5ss2kYnNC+JFf8vxUHH79cdtGlMe6xKYI1B93/kzZHalg/ZFWybsC4mXfLSouG k9QP7aon2xWGgYz65/aQqFtMaCtObCmCeb7uuhjc/gu1f8ECQQDHY5ig52Rvqi8+ 2UfkukbNAC6QD11jlI1+RJvhv4Aw0oYfSX3K7NTancDtdP2PCHffG2JpX3kR7Kkg rGWXSaZLAkEAuVzBKort8B4VHccLFhwEXbtbKX0JmdZllDNS2GiX8YoAuIyYjLdU 3aSQKxq7VYOv5DZuc/XzmW8LT5reB8Y5eQJAO0QHYgxldiuHz46WKA6WbOjY7kki 4S6OwDF0hC1/1QM+ip41ndO3kSPC7NIRbCqANvjUz61pN0K5ItUbfVSO8QJAWsX/ mrPafcJdmO2Gklc6FCTSKekfsIR7zi2sHmpqLlDktXu0oQSOvNP//fvjTadllZ7K TGNf3f2xTlSK8seyEQJBALU83M4DWQmN/9Mzp4h9XSb2wYFNfgUSJqhx2FIIvXrR GtDPlmPUlR8DoqGLCyTA/MMDum+0pdYStEWmR5ohLuQ= -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----


-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- MIGJAoGBAJBfN4pZqBgiot558BwUYZ+f6SnsfojvtD0TVLeWkgbERSZJ55wswsLk ss+rfZtkM/Q4BXJ2r9mb7EIYaZaRDWTVmkr6G4L3N5YvHFUVeHrs1/yzVd0A4j2s ddR9rU/a6TAcwgqfQ2mMAU3MGpfaE2YU0R7ei0lDAF6WdECS2ExzAgMBAAE= -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

### "User Keys"

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIICWwIBAAKBgQCDbFBVWh94E0/2tmAZJ0E0oeX3DHuz/s2URtfJUTX5P7sp5MgD zKQ5kWdXbPPprG9d9QGl9koQFkMvaPZQScvUH/yGHEKyoYQLJfzWA85L1uliSmPt wb/5R26gLS9xqjetCV+VJpIXQ7FwUTkH0fFFpgMrbNASYIarPku7bfv+3wIDAQAB AoGAA3J43PRDNQwUod0AwkgkTrQcaxF5wSviyovdJxupNcN1LlEg6fCZMiVdN47V CwEJ3sYJaAgAw1FCK+Et7McywHCS3Cw61vy/vt5+q9LwYE5x+5NhbJOV6UPgR34F ClZSPA7ELZmaK5IKh97+eAyTsUcOJxejwWeoBLQdHZqrNWkCQQCHzDl3cvdzYDC0 c07CLhsZjhTm4BMM/+oT3wOhAYA70ti7s0JEcwCB7bYkVE2ZLUFGgLk+emG7pIfX I9NUmIILAkEA98DLERPBy0tf/gpy6W7cLXQFQWlaLvGsWQI6XL4MVSP9tD8bqk8q YiPx8ZI3m9ane3FyXF/1iNKYvDfiLKCu/QJAOMmQZoEvNZJOC8gEcXNyZbdiykF9 9fu22WRzUgscoufDNor59UHaPns3pe2THbEtENyXmqb2488j9zXGFCRKjQJAV85p ae0BowZcyBF19ouG10kmT6+B+d9HQOiMPLBSeJ5f3VD8ghi6obuxlPdIZB/ojdSA PoL3530UCqkXrM9qFQJANy5KrTAtH4mTY7KW9BymA8bQRVBgQdAvNRCsBOCjnIPj M26rCOjS1BbrmuHKtoZztQeH9G+cu/iFtCPAvf0eig== -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- MIGJAoGBAINsUFVaH3gTT/a2YBknQTSh5fcMe7P+zZRG18lRNfk/uynkyAPMpDmR Z1ds8+msb131AaX2ShAWQy9o9lBJy9Qf/IYcQrKhhAsl/NYDzkvW6WJKY+3Bv/lH bqAtL3GqN60JX5UmkhdDsXBROQfR8UWmAyts0BJghqs+S7tt+/7fAgMBAAE= -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```